# program doesn't return 0. It works but returns a very big negative number

Tags: c, linked-list

This code inserts nodes at a beginning of a list. I compiled it and it works perfectly the only problem is that the process does not return 0 but a very big negative number. How can i solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int data;

struct nodo
{
    data el;
    struct nodo *next;
};

typedef struct nodo *lista;


void inserisci_in_testa (lista *l, data el);

void print (lista temp1);



int main ()
{
    lista l;
    lista *s;
    s=&l;
    inserisci_in_testa(s,10);
    inserisci_in_testa(s,1);
    inserisci_in_testa(s,7);
    print(l);
    return 0;


}

void inserisci_in_testa (lista *l, data el)
{
    lista p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    p->el = el;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
}

void print (lista temp1)
{
    while (temp1!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp1->el);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the number it returns. Converted to hexadecimal representation, it will likely be an error code. Which means `return 0;` isn't actually reached but instead there's a segmentation fault for instance because of a bug in your code, and the program was aborted.

Comment: Unrelated, every time a pointer type is hidden in a `typedef` alias, a kitten dies. Don't kill kittens. There are two exceptions to that, and neither are at play here. To your question, change `lista l;` to `lista l = NULL;`, (and yes, that really hurt to write). Your initial list head pointer, `l`, is used to set the first-inserted node's `next` pointer. Being an indeterminate value, your program invokes undefined behavior when you eventually try to dereference that pointer (such as when you print).

Comment: process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: @Sam_mb_98 they say it is rude to ask people to google but next time please google the hex code first: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/application-error-0xc0000005/6224ae45-a251-4f21-b076-74524618d00a

Comment: thank you very much WhozCraig you gave me very helpful tips. Now it returns 0.

Comment: In case you're wondering, that "big number" was an access violation followed by program termination. Running to the end of the list, then dereferencing a garbage indeterminate pointer because it isn't a determine NULL will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your insertion function does this:

```
p->el = el;
p->next = *l;
```

where `l` contains the address of the list head you passed in. On the initial node insertion, that pointer must be NULL (properly so to indicate an empty list). But yours....

```
lista l;
```

There is no determinate value assigned to `l`. If you want that to be initially NULL, you have to say so:

```
lista l = NULL;
```

Doing this, your program completes without runtime errors.